# Given desired overshoot graphically find k from the root locus (Scilab)

Tags: control-system, feedback, diagram, graph, root-locus

I want to find \$k_1\$ that leads to the feedbakc system having poles in the 53º line (to have overshoot \$\leq 10\%\$). From the root locus, the poles move along the vertical asymptote centered on -1. How can I find \$k_1\$ using Scilab and how can I draw diagonal lines representing the 53º line in which I want my poles to be at?

So far, I made this graph in Scilab,

Code:

```
s=%s;
num=2;
den=s*(s+2)
t=syslin('c',num/den);
clf;
evans(t);
mtlb_axis([-10 10 -2 2]);
```

Obtained graph:

[image]

Desired graph:

[image]

Comment: To draw the asymptotes there is a formula, https://web.calpoly.edu/~fowen/me422/RootLocus6.html

Comment: @jDAQ I know the formula but I don't know how to implement it in Scilab. Could you help please?

Comment: I think that scilab is already doing it, but since the poles go along a line they go exactly over the asymptotes, try a third order system and you might see a difference in the asymptotes and pole path

Comment: The axes must have the same scales if you're going to use geometry.

Comment: @jDAQ the diagonal dashed line is given by overshoot, so the Scilab didn't draw this lines in the graph and I want to add to the graph manually. I want to know the intersection between root locus and the overshoot line to know the k of control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, drawing two more lines with angles 53⁰ and -53⁰ should be easy, just do another plot while keeping the root locus. The lines should be,
$$ y = \tan(53^\circ)x$$ and, $$ y = -\tan(53^\circ)x.$$

Once you have those lines, set some \$k\$ to be the maximum value of the `evans` function and change that value until you find the one that lies on the line you plotted. I would use a binary search to pick the values of \$k\$.

```
s=%s;
num=2;
den=s*(s+2)
t=syslin('c',num/den);
clf;

//test your k by changing this
k = 100;

evans(t,k);
mtlb_axis([-10 10 -2 2]);

//draw the 53 deg line
r = linspace(0,-3,10);
up_line = tan(53*%pi/180)*r;
dn_line = -tan(53*%pi/180)*r;
plot(r,[up_line; dn_line],'r-.')

//pzmap of the system with feedback
figure
plzr(1/.(t*k))

//draw the 53 deg line
r = linspace(0,-3,10);
up_line = tan(53*%pi/180)*r;
dn_line = -tan(53*%pi/180)*r;
plot(r,[up_line; dn_line],'r-.')
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the code in my computer crash in the line: plzr(1/.(t*k))

Comment: it runs fine on my computer, try this, https://cloud.scilab.in/

Comment: You can also delete the code from figure downwards, that is just a pole-zero map, the root locus is done by the previous lines.

Comment: Just to confirm: Scilab makes a 0 to infinity k scanner. If I want to make the k scanner from -infinity to 0, I need to add minus signal into the function numerator, right?

Comment: Yes, from zero to positive infinity

Comment: The G(s) is $\frac{-2}{s(s+2)}$. Like q=-2<0 and k<0 (due to Routh-Hurwitz), I need to put in Scilab the function $\frac{2}{s(s+2)}$, without the minus signal in numerator, right? (because I need to study k from: -infinity to 0 and Scilab only give me the study of k from 0 to infinity)